# Scroll Through Multiple TexView in Nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, scrollbars

xml file for my About Screen .. i've done this because my app supports API 9 which does not support `DialogFragments`, so i am using another class to display another screen instead .. the problem is, i cant seem to scroll through the whole page, my .xml contains nested `LinearLayout` that also has `TextViews` .. i tried adding `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to the main <`LinearLayout`> but nothing happens .. i hope someone can help me out, thanks :)

[My XML file Pasted here.](http://pastebin.com/yAhCmisL)

Comment: you can use the support library to add dialog fragments in your code

Comment: when i add a ScrollView between the main LinearLayout and the second LinearLayout .. this is what appears,

Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView can only support a single child. So enclose your nested LinearLayouts inside a single LinearLayout and further enclose that parent LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. I have done this for you. You can use this http://pastie.org/9528662

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your root LinearLayout with ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--your nested linearlayouts here-->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: when i add a ScrollView between the main LinearLayout and the second LinearLayout .. this is what appears, Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child